# How to select specific line from CSV file using unique value

Tags: java, opencsv

I have a few line CSV file which contains these values:

```
2, Joe, BMW
6, Mark, Audio
7, Jeff, Fiat
9, Mike, Toyota
```

Now I know how to select specific line using OpenCSV ie. line 1, 2 or 3 etc. But I don't know how to select line which has first value 6 for example. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

```
Reader reader = new FileReader("data.csv");
List<String[]> rows = new CSVReader(reader).readAll();

for(String[] column: rows) {
if (column[1].equals("6")){
    System.out.println("Found row No. is " + rows.indexOf(column));
}
}
```

Comment: Though you probably want to use `readNext()` instead of `readAll()` - you don't want to get to the end of the CSV file and realize you wanted the 2nd line.

Comment: `if (column[1] == "6"){`?? NEVER compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods, on the other hand, check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Answer (score 0):

@Dharanae

You should be using `String[] rows` instead of `List<String[]> rows` because `readNext()` returns you a `String[]`